# Resolving types in F-bounded polymorphism

Tags: scala, generics, f-bounded-polymorphism

I have these models:

```
trait Vehicle[T <: Vehicle[T]] { def update(): T }
class Car extends Vehicle[Car] { def update() = new Car() }
class Bus extends Vehicle[Bus] { def update() = new Bus() }
```

If I obtain an instance of a `Vehicle[Car]` and invoke `update()`, I will get a `Car`. Since `Car` extends `Vehicle[Car]` (or simply put, Car *is a* Vehicle[Car]), I can safely set the type of the result explicitly to `Vehicle[Car]`:

```
val car = new Car
val anotherCar = car.update()
val anotherCarAsVehicle: Vehicle[Car] = car.update() // works as expected
```

But if I want to, say, put instances of `Car` and `Bus` together into one list, then I have to set the list type to `Vehicle[_ <: Vehicle[_]]` (having a list of simply `Vehicle[_]` and invoking `update()` on an element would yield `Any`, but I want to be able to use `update()` so I have to use the F-bounded type). Using existential types screws up the type relationships, because once I fetch the underlying car/bus from the Vehicle, I can no longer cast it to Vehicle because... well, it's just some existential type:

```
val seq = List[Vehicle[_ <: Vehicle[_]]](new Car, new Bus)
val car = seq.head.update()
val carAsVehicle: Vehicle[_ <: Vehicle[_]] = seq.head.update() // fails to compile
```

So, `Vehicle` is parameterized with some type `T` which is a subtype of `Vehicle[T]`. When I rip out the `T` (by using `update()`), in case of concrete types it's ok - e.g. if I rip out the `Car`, I can safely claim that I ripped out a `Vehicle[Car]` because `Car <: Vehicle[Car]`. But if I rip out an existential type, I can't do anything with it. Earlier example worked because `Car` is a `Vehicle[Car]`, but in this case `_` is not a `Vehicle[_]`.

To specify **my concrete question**: **for models given above (Vehicle, Car, Bus), is there a way to achieve this?**

```
def sameType[T, U](a: T, b: U)(implicit evidence: T =:= U) = true

val seq = List[Vehicle[_ <: Vehicle[_]]](new Car, new Bus)

sameType(seq.head.update +: seq.tail, seq) // true
```

Note that you can change the given traits, classes and type of `seq`, but there's one restriction: `update()` **must return `T`, not `Vehicle[T]`**.

I know that using shapeless `HList` would solve the problem as I wouldn't have to use existential types (I would simply have a list of a car and a bus, and that type information would be preserved). But I'm wondering for this particular use case with a simple `List`.

**EDIT**:

@RomKazanova yes, that would work of course, but I need to retain the same type before and after `update()` (here's an upvote for the effort though ;)).

I believe that it's not possible without HList or similar data structure, because unifying cars and buses forces us to use the vehicle type which loses info about whether its underlying type was Car, Bus or something else (all we can know is that it was some type `_ <: Vehicle`). But I want to check with you guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not very good with existential types, so I can't explain too much about this :-p But when you change the type of `seq` to `List[Vehicle[T] forSome {type T <: Vehicle[T]}]` everything seems to "work out". Mind you have to pass the type to the `List` constructor/apply method.

```
scala> val seq = List[Vehicle[T] forSome {type T <: Vehicle[T]}](new Car, new Bus)
seq: List[Vehicle[T] forSome { type T <: Vehicle[T] }] = List(Car@31e53802, Bus@54d569e7)

scala> sameType(seq.head.update +: seq.tail, seq)
res3: Boolean = true

scala> seq.head.update
res4: T forSome { type T <: Vehicle[T] } = Car@79875bd2

scala> seq.head.update.update
res5: T forSome { type T <: Vehicle[T] } = Car@6928c6a0

scala> new Car +: seq
res6: List[Vehicle[T] forSome { type T <: Vehicle[T] }] = List(Car@51f0a09b, Car@31e53802, Bus@54d569e7)
```

I think the main thing to get out of this answer is that this lets you spell out the recursive nature of the `Vehicle` type constructor.

I'm not sure I would recommend this though...

Comment: I would have thought that `List[Vehicle[_ <: Vehicle[_]]]` is the same type as `List[Vehicle[T] forSome {type T <: Vehicle[T]}]`. As a general rule of thumb I wouldn't mind using `forSome` everywhere, but I heard it's being evicted in Scala 2.13 or 2.14. Anyways, thank you very much, this is exactly the kind of solution I was hoping for.

Comment: I did elide all the existential type warnings from my REPL transcript. So I think this is the kind of existential that is inexpressible with only wildcards. I'm not sure *if* it will be completely removed, but if yes then I *think* the soonest would be when Dotty becomes Scala 3.0 or something like that.

Comment: @slouc One possible intuition to explain why this works: in `List[Vehicle[_ <: Vehicle[_]]]`, the first `_` and second `_` are 2 completely unrelated types, whereas in `List[Vehicle[T] forSome {type T <: Vehicle[T]}]` you explicitly mention the same type `T` twice.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to resolve it:

```
val carAsVehicle: Vehicle[_] = seq.head.update()
```

or use pattern matching

```
val carAsVehicle: Vehicle[Car] = seq.head match {
  case car: Vehicle[Car] => car.update()
}
```

But interesting that:

```
val seq = List[Vehicle[_ <: Vehicle[_]]](new Car, new Bus)

val vehicleAsVihecles: List[Vehicle[_]]= seq.map(_.update()) // compiled

val vehicleAsVihecles1: List[Vehicle[_ <: Vehicle[_]]]= seq.map(_.update()) //not compiled

def somedef(vehicles: List[Vehicle[_ <: Vehicle[_]]]) = vehicles.map(_.update()) //compiled
somedef(seq)
```